# how to get exit code when using xargs (parallel)

Tags: linux, bash, rsync, xargs

I'd made a script for launching parallel rsync process:

```
#! /bin/bash
LIST=$1
DEST_DIR=$2
RSYNC_OPTS=$3
#echo "rsyncing From=$SRC_DIR To=$DEST_DIR RSYNC_OPTS=$RSYNC_OPTS"
echo $LIST|xargs -n1 -d, echo|xargs -n1 -P 0 -I% rsync --rsync-path='sudo rsync' ${RSYNC_OPTS} % ${DEST_DIR}
```

Then, I have problems to get the exit status of the rsync process. I know that is possible to get an array of pipestatus, but I need to catch the exit code to know if the rsync was made successfully or not.

Anyone knows?

Comment: You already mentioned `$PIPESTATUS`: `${PIPESTATUS[2]}` will contain the exit status of the second `xargs` command. This will be 123 if `rsync` exited with a status of 1-125 (see the exit status section here: http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?xargs)

Comment: Hi Josh, thanks for your reply. Nevertheless, I need the exit code of the rysnc, not the xargs exit code. Something like this : http://wpkg.org/Rsync_exit_codes

Comment: Not sure you would be able to get the rsync's specific exit status using xargs like this, it will be masked by xargs. Maybe you could loop through `$LIST` instead?

Comment: duplicate question: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/124649/4667

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The man page for xargs shows the possible exit status values, however it can only produce a single aggregated exit code, not an exit code per child that it runs.  You could try one of these options:

- Have the process that xargs spawns print its exit code and have the parent task parse all the exit code outputs to determine the exit code for each rsync.
- Use GNU [parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html) with the `--joblog` option.  This will create a file containing all the commands which were run in parallel along with its exit code and other information.  This file could then be parsed after `parallel` exits to determine which rsync commands failed and their respective error codes.